# Can an asset be owned by multiple owners in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I want to build a database with hyperledger fabric, but in an asset can be update by different user. Is it possible to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes. But you have to define the details more. Own and update are not necessarily the same thing. It depends on how you define the asset, the functions that are created to modify the asset, and the rules for who can access each function for that asset. You can make all of that whatever you want it to be.

Comment: thank you, i will try to make the function in smart contract first